# loading images from e folder and display them in html

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi guys by using the following code I am trying to read all images from a folder and then to display them in my html file. The problem is how you can see the /images/ folder is in /fetch/ folder. When the images are displayed are loaded like /fetch/frame_1.jpg instead /fetch/images/frame_1.jpg so in this case to display them I have to use twice the images set. One in the image folder and one in the fetch folder. Can anyone explain to me why is this?

```
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dir = "/fetch/images/";
            var fileExtension = ".jpg";
            $.ajax({
                url: dir,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileExtension + ")").each(function () {
                        var fileName = this.href.replace(window.location.host, "").replace("http://", "");
                        $("body").append("<img src='"+ fileName + "'>");
                        console.log(fileName);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes got me images. 
1) remove forward/back slash from var dir.
2) combining dir and name of file.

Below is the code that worked for me:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var dir = "fetch/images/";
        var fileExtension = ".jpg";
        $.ajax({
            url: dir,
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileExtension + ")").each(function () {
                    var fn = this.href.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
                    var fileName = dir + fn;
                    $("body").append("<img src='"+ fileName + "'>");
                    console.log(fileName);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```